# Three options for SQL WHERE clause, the third of which could be LIKE either of the first two

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database application (MS Access) in which the hours that employees were paid for based on reported hours are compared to the hours they were on site via a fingerprinting in and out system.  The boxes that record the fingerprint punches can give three possible "punch markers" which are "in" "out" "auto".  If the security guard fails to choose in or out then the data record will have a marker of auto.

The application finds a total number of hours on site via 2 queries:

1:

```
WHERE Marker LIKE "in"
```

2:

```
WHERE Marker LIKE "out"
```

and then subtracting the "in" punch from the "out" punch for a particular employee.  This works fine until we have an "auto" punch.  In this case the employee is reported to have been here 0 hours.  I thought about doing:

```
WHERE Marker LIKE "out" or "auto"
```

But I can't say for sure that the "auto" marker will be the out time.  Sometimes it should be in time.

[Here is a screenshot of a small piece of the data I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEMT2.png)

The in out marker is here called "mode".

I would love thoughts and/or brainstorming on how I might make this work;

Comment: Your question makes no sense without sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are there multiple "shifts" and does one of them span midnight so there is a date change? You will need to cover all shifts in your sample data.

Comment: And what if you have two subsequent "auto"s?

Comment: @Used_By_Already There aren't really distinct shifts, just a record of when someone shows up and the security guard hitting the in or out button.  Problem is they often fail to hit a button, which then gives "auto".

Comment: @Gustav another good question, I'm going over the answer offered below to see whether it can handle all of the possible scenarios of these three options in two places.  I have even gotten 2 ins and no outs, and on one occasion 1 in and 2 outs which should not be happening, but since it is I have to deal with it.

Comment: I've added a screenshot example of data @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better if you set a new field and call it '`button_option`' and set the default value as '`auto`' , then use `marker` like a (temporary clothes hook) !!

> basically record the callback value of ***Marker*** from ***button_option*** 
>   
>   - **if** button_option = 'in' 
>   ,`Marker = 'in'` **if** button_option = out ,`Marker = out` 
>   
>  - **if** `"button_option"` is `'auto'` the callback will be reversed based on last value available in `Marker`. 
>     which is what the employee choose ***last time***

then your auto recording process in `ms-access > sql` should look like :

```
iif (button_option= 'auto' && Marker = 'in', "out", "in");
```

logically mean :

```
If [button_option] = 'auto' && [Marker] = 'in' Then
  Marker = "out"
Else
  Marker = "in"
End If
```

Translation :

```
if employee set the button auto -AND- his last choice was 'out' then he should be 'in' cause he cant be out twice without in !!
```

Example of using iif() function in a query in Microsoft Access :

### [Click HERE to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeEjF.png)

u can use the image example above also to callback the value without creating button_option , but it would be more messy and complicated for you

Comment: I feel like this is one the right track, maybe the screenshot I added to the OP will help?  Good example records are for Employee ID 1350.  He obviously left during the "Auto" punch.
If I'm understanding your answer correctly I need to go back before the splitting the punch types into in and out in separate queries and instead use if the IIf statement in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, the way that I ended up doing this was actually much more simple than I had originally made it.  I had to speak with the powers that be and get permission to ignore the markers, at which point I did this:

```
SELECT 
[0120Monday].[Employee ID],
MAX(TimeValue([0120Monday].PunchTime)) AS OutTime, 
MIN(TimeValue([0120Monday].PunchTime)) AS InTime

FROM
0120Monday

GROUP BY
[0120Monday].[Employee ID];
```

Of course I had to explain that this is not eliminating the errors being created by the security officers, just ignoring them.  For us this will suffice, however I do believe that the answer by THE NEXT SJ would have solved the problem had ignoring this error riddled piece of the data not been acceptable.